# Weird output, when number starts with 0

Tags: php, numbers, octal

1. script:

```
$num = "00445790";
echo $num;
```

returns:

```
00445790
```

2. script

```
$num = 00445790;
echo $num;
```

returns:

```
2351
```

Can somebody explain why I get `2351` on the second script?

Comment: You need to learn about data types

Comment: And here is where to start http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php

Comment: I reopen this question that the original dupe did not cover the effect the `9` had in the number.

Comment: @JohnConde Thanks, I completely overlooked that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Integers`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) that start with zero are consider octal. Because octal integers only use numbers from 0 to 8 everything from the `9` on are ignored.

So `00445790` becomes `004457` which is `2351` in decimal.

Comment: Thanks, that really cleared it up. I was really confused as to why this was happening, but it makes a lot of sense! Thanks again.

Comment: This sounds odd. Even if PHP is an interpreter language it can find out that the digit sequence is somehow incorrect (it is a wrong octal if the leading zero is predominant) and should raise a warning. Or recognize that it's actually a decimal number and treat it as such. (My PHP days are a bit ago...)

Comment: @ThomasKilian A warning would finitely be helpful in a situation like this instead of a potentially difficult to spot bug.

Comment: I just fired up my old PHP and indeed it silently swallows the rest of the number. Strange nobody ever has reported that as bug looking at the number of PHP installations out there :-/

Comment: @ThomasKilian I guess it has just always been considered acceptable behavior. :/

Comment: Ya, lol. People accept the pain of a nail in the foot if they get hammered on their head all time.